# mapping article and category entity to my article_category table

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

So I have 2 entities:

```
Article
Category
```

And I have a table that relates the articleID and categoryID:

```
articles_categories
-articleID
-categoryID
```

I am using xml for my mappings, what should I do here?

**I want to be able to query for all articles in a given category.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use many to many mapping:

```
<class name="Article">     

<set name="Categories" table="articles_categories">
  <key column="ArticleId" />
  <many-to-many column="CategoryId" class="Category"  />
</set>


</class>
```

You should be able to query like a normal collection.

Comment: how would I associate an article to a category?

Comment: Like the mapping describes above

the class would be like this: 
class Article
{
   ISet<Category> Categories {get;set;}
   
}

Comment: ok thanks. so then I should create helper methods on both classes that add to each others collections correcT?

Answer (score 1):

You can approach this in two ways, depending on how you want to do it.  You can set your Category class to have a Collection of Articles.  Then to get all of the articles in the category you simply load the Category by id and then call getArticles().

Alternatively, you give the Article a collection of Categories that it belongs to.  It all depends on your domain model.  Can an article be in multiple categories?

Once you've decided that, take a look at the Hibernate documentation on mapping Collections: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html_single/#collections

Then your query would look something like the following:

```
select a from Article a join a.categories c where c.categoryID = :yourCategoryId
```